# Why is this object not positioned properly with Auto Layout?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I place an image view (content size: aspect fit) on my base layout. I create the trailing, leading and bottom constraints and set their `constant`s to 0.

[image]

This doesn't happen when the image is smaller than the view:

[image]

Though, the image isn't positioned properly on the iPhone - it appears almost centered - while it is on the iPad. Perhaps its intrinsic content size is too big? Why is this happening?

Comment: what content mode is set? what is the size of the image compared to the view?

Comment: @Wain: aspect fit and the image view doesn't hold any image.

Comment: Do you have a top, height, or aspect ratio constraint?

Comment: Try changing the background color of the image view, I don't think the placeholder image is a reliable indication of the frame.

Comment: I have the issue when the image is bigger than the view; I used a real image, about 1500x1500px big.

Comment: Did you set an placeholder intrinsic size?

Comment: @jcaron I used a real image instead - I didn't.

Comment: I believe the issue is related to the fact that the size used for auto-layout is the actual picture size, and then the Aspect Fit content mode only uses a small portion of the available space (as the aspect ratio is not the same)

Comment: I think the clipstobounds is turned off

Comment: @jcaron Thanks - What can I do to fix this? I liked Aspect Fit because it scaled my images just fine.

Comment: Add an aspect ratio constraint on the image with the same aspect ratio as your actual image.

Comment: @jcaron Please feel free to post your last comment as an answer - it fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you haven't set a top, aspect ratio, or height constraint on your image view, iOS falls back to the intrinsic content size (the actual size of the image) **for the height only** (the width is set by the leading/trailing constraints). If the image is wider than the screen, it will result in an image view that is as tall as the original image, but with the with set to the screen width.

Then, as you have the content mode set to Aspect Fit, iOS places your resized image inside the image view, and leaves lots of blank space around it.

One option to resolve this is to add an aspect ratio contraint on the image view, matching the aspect ratio of the image inside it. This will result in a correct height for the image view.

Answer (score 0):

beyowulf was correct i believe. You should try changing the background color of imageview. If you change the imageview background color, you will realise that imageview always obeys your auto-layout constraint.

Now why not image??
Its because you asked it not to :) aspect fit will try to resize the image still maintaining the aspect ratio :) when the size of the image is too large i.e greater than the size of imageview frame, image covers the full frame of imageview and maintains the aspect ratio as well. Meaning if width is greater than screen width, image will cover the imageview frame width and takes a corresponding height for that width.

Thats why in first case your image covers full imageview frame where as in second where image size is small covers only space required :)

If on the other hand you want image to cover imageview frame always either fall back to scale to fill or aspect fill based on your requirement.

Happy coding :)

Comment: Aspect Fill covers the entire screen on the iPhone - I don't want it to. What can I do so that the image stays on the bottom? Please note I'm using an actual image - I don't follow why you need a background color for it.

Comment: background color will not solve your issue buddy :) just wanted you to realize that imageview frame always follow your auto layout constraint. So your autolayout constraints are correct :)